# Excel index match with multiple criteria referencing another workbook

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I ran this formula with a single criteria and it works, but when I try to use an array formula for multiple criteria it doesn't work. Any help would be really appreciated. Here's the code:

```
{=INDEX(INDIRECT("'["&'MSA Index'!$H$7&"]"&'MSA Index'!$N$2&"'!"&'MSA 
Index'!$N$3),MATCH(1,(B4=INDIRECT("'["&'MSA Index'!$H$7&"]"&'MSA 
Index'!$N$2&"'!"&'MSA Index'!$N$4))*('MSA Index'!$H$4=INDIRECT("'["&'MSA 
Index'!$H$7&"]"&'MSA Index'!$N$2&"'!"&'MSA Index'!$N$5)),0))}
```

I've gone through a few times and it looks correct. Is this a limitation of excel?

Comment: Does it work if you put the references in directly without the INDIRECT?  Also, as a note; Indirect requires that the workbook be open.

Comment: Yes, without the indirect functions the references work. I am also aware that the workbook must be open and have been trying it with it open.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the formula in my own file and it works correctly so if it results in error for you it has to be because of values in the cells you use to get workbook, worksheet & column names or the condition. In the conditions there is the only inconsistency I can see - is it ok that you use only `B4` in your first condition, but `'MSA Index'!$H$4` in your second condition?

Comment: B4 references a markets name, while 'MSA Index'!$H$4 references a year (2017,2018, etc.). I have tried using index/match functions with indirect and they work, the only issue I run into is when I try to match for multiple criteria.